# How to get thumbnail image content from thumbnail URL using You Tube API v3

Tags: youtube-data-api

I tried this in 2 ways:

First:

```
$url= "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2ve6PEagFJc/maxresdefault.jpg";   
$curl = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, (string)$url);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);   
$raw_contents = curl_exec($curl);//(it is returning **false** always)  
curl_close($curl);
```

Second:

```
$url="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2ve6PEagFJc/maxresdefault.jpg";  
echo $data=file_get_contents($url);   //(it is returning **false** always)
```

How can I get thumbnail image content using `YouTube api v3` in php?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
$url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2ve6PEagFJc/maxresdefault.jpg";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$cont = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents('/tmp/2ve6PEagFJc.jpg',print_r($cont,true));
```